# Dynamic database connection Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i need to connect two database. the default database is fixed but the other one is dynamic, its based on URL.

for example if url is : yourapp.myweb.com then second database name will be **yourapp**

i try connect database into **init**.py but its show me following error

```
builtins.AssertionError
AssertionError: A setup function was called after the first request was handled.  This usually indicates a bug in the application where a module was not imported and decorators or other functionality was called too late.
To fix this make sure to import all your view modules, database models and everything related at a central place before the application starts serving requests.
```

here is my **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask,session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='/static')

#  Database Connection
database = request.url.split("/")[2].split(".")[0]
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/main_database"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'user_db': 'mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/database_'+str(database), #dynamic Connection
}
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()
db.create_all(bind=['user_db'])
# db.init_app(app)

from . import views
```

here is the viwe.py

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    try:
        from .model import Users
        # Some Code
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
        # return "Failed to login ! Please try again."
```

here is the model.py

```
from application import db
class Users(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'user_db'
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password = db.Column(db.String())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.name
```

Comment: i think when i start my app it has no any request.url so may be..

Comment: if there is above problem then which .py file is best to connect database ?

Comment: Try placing `from .model import Users` at the top level of the module.

Comment: i tried that. it's not work. ):

Comment: The code works for me if I use sqlite instead of mysql. I suspect the problem is you're not able to successfully connect to the databases. Is it possible that you're missing the [Python3 port of pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python)?

Comment: Thanks @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta the thing is pymysql is installed. if debug  is true its show above error other wise it not show any error and works good

Comment: I've added a few more suggestions in an answer. Please have a look and let me know whether any of those point to the issue or not.

Comment: @KaushikMakwana Have you got any solution?

Comment: Why do you use the bind in `db.create_all(bind=['user_db'])`?

Answer (score 3):

As I said in one of my comments, this might be a problem with the database connection. Here's what I'd check for:

1. First of all, make sure you have the right engine installed in your virtual environment (you can check easily by running `pip list`; just in case, let me insist that libraries need to be installed in a [virtual environment](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)). Make sure you have not `pymysql`, but the port to Python3, called [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python). `pymysql` only works with Python2. In order to install this library, you need to install first the Python and MySQL development headers. For example, in Debian/Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
   ```

   Then you can install the library with the following command:

   ```
   pip install mysqlclient
   ```
2. If this is installed, make sure you can actually connect to the database using the library. Open a Python shell within the virtual environment and type the following (from the example in [github](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)):

   ```
   import pymysql.cursors

   connection = pymysql.connect(host='<you_host>',
                                user='<user>',
                                password='<password>',
                                db='<database_name>',
                                charset='utf8mb4',
                                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

   try:
       with connection.cursor() as cursor:
           do_something()
   except:
       pass
   ```
3. If this works, make sure you're running the most recent version of Flask ([0.12 at the moment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask/0.12); this again you can check by running `pip list`), as there are several bugs related to running Flask in DEBUG mode that have been fixed over time.
4. It's surely not the case here, but another sanity check is verifying that no other process is running on the port that you want to use for Flask.

If all of the above is working fine, I'd need to see a bit of the stack trace to figure out what is actually going on.

Comment: Antonio Haro thanks your suggestion. but its still give error.

Comment: the thing is i need to get database name from url and i try to get database nane like this  database = request.url.split("/")[2].split(".")[0] its stopped from here.